# Finding percentage of profitable investments with pandas groupby functionality

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this; it shows a history of stock investing. In the Profit column, 1 means profitable and 0 means loss-making.

```
Stock  Year   Profit  Count
 AAPL  2012    0       23
 AAPL  2012    1       19
 AAPL  2013    0       20
 AAPL  2013    1       10
GOOG   2012    0       26
GOOG   2012    1       20
GOOG   2013    0       23
GOOG   2013    1       11
```

I have to find out the percentage of profitable investments:

```
Stock  Year   Profit  CountPercent
 AAPL  2012    1       38.77
 AAPL  2013    1       33.33
GOOG   2012    1       43.47
GOOG   2013    1       32.35
```

I tried using the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)
 but it shows `'TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous'`.

Comment: Please provide your code. What is `CountPercent` meant to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have loaded your data into a dataframe called "stocks".

```
# Get the count of profitable trades, indexed by stock+year:
count_profitable = stocks[ stocks['Profit']==1 ].set_index(['Stock','Year']).Count
# Get the count of all trades, indexed by stock + year:
count_all        = stocks.groupby(['Stock','Year']).Count.sum()
# Render nice percentages
pandas.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}%'.format 
(count_profitable/count_all) * 100
```

This will produce:

```
Stock  Year
AAPL   2012   45.24%
       2013   33.33%
GOOG   2012   43.48%
       2013   32.35%
Name: Count, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations):

```
In [38]: result = df.pivot_table(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='Profit', values='Count', aggfunc='sum')

In [39]: result['CountPercent'] = result[1]/(result[0]+result[1])

In [41]: result['CountPercent']
Out[41]: 
Stock  Year
AAPL   2012    0.452381
       2013    0.333333
GOOG   2012    0.434783
       2013    0.323529
Name: CountPercent, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DataFrame is in a consistent format (namely that 0 precedes 1 in the 'Profit' column), you could do the following `groupby` operations:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(['Stock', 'Year'])
>>> perc = grouped['Count'].last() / grouped['Count'].sum()
>>> perc.reset_index()
  Stock  Year     Count
0  AAPL  2012  0.452381
1  AAPL  2013  0.333333
2  GOOG  2012  0.434783
3  GOOG  2013  0.323529
```

This is just a normal DataFrame, so it should be straightforward to rename the 'Count' column, round it to two decimal places and add the 'Profit' column back in.