# How to use groupby transform across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe, and I'm grouping by one to n columns, and want to apply a function on these groups across two columns (e.g. foo and bar).

Here's an example dataframe:

```
foo_function = lambda x: np.sum(x.a+x.b)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'c':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
                   'd':['z','z','z','o','o','o']})

# works with apply, but I want transform:
df.groupby(['c', 'd'])[['a','b']].apply(foo_function)
# transform doesn't work!
df.groupby(['c', 'd'])[['a','b']].transform(foo_function)
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

But `transform` apparently isn't able to combine multiple columns together because it looks at each column separately (unlike apply). What is the next best alternative in terms of speed /  elegance? e.g. I could use `apply` and then create `df['new_col']` by using `pd.match`, but that would necessitate matching over sometimes multiple groupby columns (col1 and col2) which seems really hacky / would take a fair amount of code.

--> Is there a function that is like groupby().transform that can use functions that work over multiple columns? If this doesn't exist, what's the best hack?

Comment: I'm going to disagree with the accepted answer and say the best way is to use `apply` to perform the computation you want, resulting in one row per group; then use `pd.merge` to merge this result back into the original dataframe, which will give you the like-indexed dataframe that you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Circa Pandas version 0.18, it appears the original answer (below) no longer works.

Instead, if you need to do a groupby computation across multiple columns, do the multi-column computation *first*, and then the groupby:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'c':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
                   'd':['z','z','z','o','o','o']})
df['e'] = df['a'] + df['b']
df['e'] = (df.groupby(['c', 'd'])['e'].transform('sum'))
print(df)
```

yields

```
   a  b  c  d   e
0  1  1  q  z  12
1  2  2  q  z  12
2  3  3  q  z  12
3  4  4  q  o   8
4  5  5  w  o  22
5  6  6  w  o  22
```

---

Original answer:

The error message:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

suggests that in order to concatenate, the `foo_function` should return an NDFrame (such as a Series or DataFrame). If you return a Series, then:

```
In [99]: df.groupby(['c', 'd']).transform(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sum(x['a']+x['b'])))
Out[99]: 
    a   b
0  12  12
1  12  12
2  12  12
3   8   8
4  22  22
5  22  22
```

Comment: This is throwing a key error in 0.19.1. It was my understanding that transform passes a Series (each column) to the function. But very strangely it also passes a dataframe once as well when the following is ran with the above data. `df.groupby(['c', 'd']).transform(lambda x: print(type(x)))`. This looks like a bug

Comment: @TedPetrou: Thanks for pointing this out. As a performance enhancement, `transform` -- like `apply` -- might try to apply the function to (sub-)dataframes. Under certain circumstances (e.g. vectorized function and lots of columns) this could be faster than applying the function once for each group and column.

Comment: @TedPetrou: Regarding the `KeyError` -- now that I look back on my original answer, I don't think the solution I suggested is a good one. The `transform` calls the function once for each group. You get better performance if you call vectorized functions fewer times on larger inputs. Therefore, it makes more sense to compute `df['a']+df['b']` on the entire columns *before* calling `transform`. I've modified the post above to show what I mean.

Comment: Not sure if your 0.18 fix works. What if the function I want to do cannot be done outside group by? Say for each group I want `df['a'] + df['b'].shift()`

Comment: @jf328: Doing pre-computation on entire columns before doing groupby operations is good for performance *when possible*. You are correct that it is not always possible. In those cases you need to use the more [flexible apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply).

Answer (score 4):

The following workaround allows you to transform with similar `transform` syntax, using `.groupby` and `.apply` instead.

So you don't have break multi-column computation apart, hence fragmenting the processing steps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'c':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
                   'd':['z','z','z','o','o','o']})

group = ['c', 'd']
df['result'] = df.groupby(group)\
    .apply(
        # your typical transform function here
        lambda df: (df.a + df.b)/df.b.sum()
    ).reset_index(group, drop=True)

df
```

```
    a   b   c   d   result
0   1   1   q   z   0.333333
1   2   2   q   z   0.666667
2   3   3   q   z   1.000000
3   4   4   q   o   2.000000
4   5   5   w   o   0.909091
5   6   6   w   o   1.090909
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I read the question, you want to be able to do something arbitrary with both the individual values from both columns. You just need to make sure to return a dataframe of the same size as you get passed in. I think the best way is to just make a new column, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'c':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
                   'd':['z','z','z','o','o','o']})
df['e']=0

def f(x):
    y=(x['a']+x['b'])/sum(x['b'])
    return pd.DataFrame({'e':y,'a':x['a'],'b':x['b']})

df.groupby(['c','d']).transform(f)
```

:

```
    a   b   e
0   1   1   0.333333
1   2   2   0.666667
2   3   3   1.000000
3   4   4   2.000000
4   5   5   0.909091
5   6   6   1.090909
```

If you have a very complicated dataframe, you can pick your columns (e.g. `df.groupby(['c'])['a','b','e'].transform(f)`)

This sure looks very inelegant to me, but it's still much faster than `apply` on large datasets.

Another alternative is to use `set_index` to capture all the columns you need and then pass just one column to `transform`.

Comment: For what it's worth, this no longer works. `transform` appears not to send the whole `df`, so you get a `KeyError` with `x['a']`. If you have another suggestion, I would love to know. Otherwise, I had to use `apply`, which operates on the whole `df`. `f(x)` becomes `x['e'] = (x['a']+x['b'])/sum(x['b'])` and then simply `return x`.

Comment: `df['e'] = (df['a'] + df['b']) / df.groupby(['c','d'])['b'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant and simple way in 2 steps, working with a group key of a single column :

1. `groupby.apply` to create a Series of values per group
2. map the original dataframe with this Series

```py
values_per_group = df.groupby(group_key).apply(
                      lambda df_group: func_on_group(df_group)
                   )

df['new_col'] = df[group_key].map(values_per_group)
```