# Subtract specific rows in Pandas, belonging to the same group of date

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I am trying to calculate the difference of a price stock in pandas between a fixed day , lets say "23.05.2021" and all the others days until today. However no idea how to do this in the simpliest way for each stock ? Probably I should use a groupby or a filter for each stock and date and then make the difference ?  Please see here the df [dataframe that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHpLR.png).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_stocks.csv")
df["difference"] = ??
print(df)

   Stock       Date        Open       Close        High         Low

0    PEP 2021-06-23  146.059998  144.850006  146.130005  144.830002
1    PEP 2021-06-24  144.860001  145.669998  145.940002  144.610001
2    PEP 2021-06-25  145.759995  146.410004  146.789993  145.240005
3    PEP 2021-06-28  146.759995  147.039993  147.589996  146.619995
4    PEP 2021-06-29  147.449997  146.940002  147.699997  146.399994
5    PEP 2021-06-30  147.429993  148.169998  148.309998  147.199997
6    PEP 2021-07-01  148.080002  148.199997  149.080002  147.940002
7    PEP 2021-07-02  148.899994  148.910004  149.779999  148.559998
8     KO 2021-06-23   54.560001   54.119999   54.599998   54.110001
9     KO 2021-06-24   54.259998   54.389999   54.419998   54.000000
10    KO 2021-06-25   54.240002   54.320000   54.470001   54.009998
11    KO 2021-06-28   54.250000   54.259998   54.369999   54.000000
12    KO 2021-06-29   54.130001   53.860001   54.340000   53.720001
13    KO 2021-06-30   53.799999   54.110001   54.180000   53.750000
14    KO 2021-07-01   54.340000   53.959999   54.480000   53.860001
15    KO 2021-07-02   54.000000   54.180000   54.450001   54.000000
16  INFY 2021-06-23   20.549999   20.690001   20.709999   20.520000
17  INFY 2021-06-24   21.350000   21.190001   21.450001   21.190001
18  INFY 2021-06-25   21.430000   21.250000   21.510000   21.129999
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpwq5.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the actual text output of your dataframe, not a link to an image. You'll also need to show the rows with values for each stock for that given date 23.05.2021.

Comment: You should **set the date as your index**. Then it would simply be `groupby('Stock')` and you could directly index the price for 23.05.2021 and subtract it from your columns of interest. When you say 'price', do you mean Open/Close/High/Low or all of these columns?

Comment: `df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`

Comment: Hi there , thanks for anwering . Sorry but not idea how to edit this post correspondingly.

Comment: Hope I can have some more details regarding the solution you have in mind :)  thx

Answer (score 0):

First, it makes your life easier to set Date as your index:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

This is much nicer, now you can directly index your dataframe by date:

```
>>> df
           Stock        Open       Close        High         Low
Date                                                            
2021-06-23   PEP  146.059998  144.850006  146.130005  144.830002
2021-06-24   PEP  144.860001  145.669998  145.940002  144.610001
2021-06-25   PEP  145.759995  146.410004  146.789993  145.240005
```

Now ordinarily we would do:

```
df.groupby('Stock', as_index=False).transform(lambda x: x-x['2021-06-23'])  # or whatever reference date you want
```

but [pandas 1.x seems to have an ongoing unfixed bug where `df.groupby(..., as_index=False)` gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099684/how-to-use-groupby-transform-across-multiple-columns) so we lose the 'Stock' column. So workaround is:

```
dfd = df.copy()
for stk in df['Stock'].unique():
    dfd.loc[dfd['Stock']==stk, ['Open','Close','High','Low']] -= dfd[dfd['Stock']==stk].loc['2021-06-23'] # or whatever reference date

>>> dfd
           Stock      Open     Close      High       Low
Date                                                    
2021-06-23   PEP       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2021-06-24   PEP -1.199997  0.819992 -0.190003 -0.220001
2021-06-25   PEP -0.300003  1.559998  0.659988  0.410003
2021-06-28   PEP  0.699997  2.189987  1.459991  1.789993
2021-06-29   PEP  1.389999  2.089996  1.569992  1.569992
2021-06-30   PEP  1.369995  3.319992  2.179993  2.369995
2021-07-01   PEP  2.020004  3.349991  2.949997      3.11
2021-07-02   PEP  2.839996  4.059998  3.649994  3.729996
2021-06-23    KO       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2021-06-24    KO -0.300003      0.27     -0.18 -0.110001
2021-06-25    KO -0.319999  0.200001 -0.129997 -0.100003
2021-06-28    KO -0.310001  0.139999 -0.229999 -0.110001
2021-06-29    KO     -0.43 -0.259998 -0.259998     -0.39
2021-06-30    KO -0.760002 -0.009998 -0.419998 -0.360001
2021-07-01    KO -0.220001     -0.16 -0.119998     -0.25
2021-07-02    KO -0.560001  0.060001 -0.149997 -0.110001
2021-06-23  INFY       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
2021-06-24  INFY  0.800001       0.5  0.740002  0.670001
2021-06-25  INFY  0.880001  0.559999  0.800001  0.609999
```

(Note we used `-=` to subtract-in-place; could have used `dfd.sub(...)`. You can do this other ways.)