# Pandas conditional groupby: aggregation over partition using predicate

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have had this task several times, so that I am wondering if it is possible to aggregate in a OVER PARTITION BY style while using a predicate.

There are dozens of examples on SO of `groupby` of window function and quite a few using a condition, but none where the condition depends on the values of the column (i.e. not based on a literal - constant value).

Consider this example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': ['0001', '0001', '0001', '0002', '0002', '0003', '0003', '0004'],
    'days': [2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8],
    'amount': [100, 150, 150, 200, 100, 300, 250, 200]
})

print(df)

     id  days  amount
0  0001     2     100
1  0001     5     150
2  0001     6     150
3  0002     3     200
4  0002     5     100
5  0003     4     300
6  0003     6     250
7  0004     8     200
```

I would like the window sum of `amount` grouped by a condition on `days`. This condition might be a less equal on `days`, i.e. given a number of `days`, calculate the sum of `amount` for all `days` up to the value of `days` in that row, i.e. `df['days'] <= i` for every row `i`.

I couldn't find any other solution other than using a loop:

```
df['run_sum_le'] = 0
for i in df.sort_values('days', ascending=False)['days'].unique():
    le = df['days'] <= i
    df.loc[le, 'run_sum_le'] = df[le]['amount'].sum()

print(df)

     id  days  amount  run_sum_le
0  0001     2     100         100
1  0001     5     150         850
2  0001     6     150        1250
3  0002     3     200         300
4  0002     5     100         850
5  0003     4     300         600
6  0003     6     250        1250
7  0004     8     200        1450
```

Note that the the correct ordering of the iterator is necessary.

Another example for more clarity: let us calculate the sum of `amount` using the condition greater equal and equal, i.e. sum `amount` using `df['days'] >= i` and `df['days'] == i` for every row `i`.

```
df['run_sum_eq'] = 0
df['run_sum_ge'] = 0
for i in df.sort_values('days', ascending=True)['days'].unique():
    eq = df['days'] == i
    ge = df['days'] >= i
    df.loc[eq, 'run_sum_eq'] = df[eq]['amount'].sum()
    df.loc[ge, 'run_sum_ge'] = df[ge]['amount'].sum()

print(df)

     id  days  amount  run_sum_le  run_sum_eq  run_sum_ge
0  0001     2     100         100         100        1450
1  0001     5     150         850         250         850
2  0001     6     150        1250         400         600
3  0002     3     200         300         200        1350
4  0002     5     100         850         250         850
5  0003     4     300         600         300        1150
6  0003     6     250        1250         400         600
7  0004     8     200        1450         200         200
```

Note 1: changed ordering in the iterator.
Note 2: this method for `eq = df['days'] == i` is an overkill because can be replaced by the one liner:

```
df['run_sum_eq'] = df['days'].map(df.groupby('days')['amount'].sum())
```

which is simply groping by `days`, i.e. it corresponds to a *regular* PARTITION BY calculation.

This last method is equivalent to:

```
df['days'].map(df.groupby('days')['amount'].agg(pd.Series.sum))
```

which leads me to think that I could use a lambda in the `agg()` where I can include the predicate:

```
df['days'].map(df.groupby('days')['amount'].agg([('amount', lambda val: ???)]))
```

and this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

How generic do you want this to be?

Solving your specific cases is straight forward...

- LE is just a cumsum
- EQ is just a sum
- GE is `total - LE + EQ` (or LE in reverse order, if you don't calculate LE and EQ first)

Which gives...

```
le = (
  df
    .sort_values('days')
    .groupby('days')['amount']
    .sum()
    .cumsum()
    .rename('le')
)

df = (
  df
    .join(le, on='days')
)
```

```
df['eq'] = (
  df
    .sort_values('days')
    .groupby('days')['amount']
    .transform(sum)
)
```

```
df['ge'] = df['amount'].sum() - df['le'] + df['eq']
```

https://trinket.io/python3/b42a02e0bc

Or, if you're really gathering all three...

```
x = (
  df
    .sort_values('days')
    .groupby('days')['amount']
    .sum()
    .rename('eq')
    .to_frame()
)

x['le'] = x['eq'].cumsum()

x['ge'] = x['eq'].sum() - x['le'] + x['eq']


print(df.join(x, on='days'))
```

Comment: I was looking for the use of a more generic predicate. I traded specificity to achieve more readability. Therefore I chose equality. My bad. But your answer is very helpful and efficient - definitely something I haven't though before.

Comment: @DomenicoSpidyTamburro It can be done with `apply(lambda)` but that's going to be exceedingly slow... https://stackoverflow.com/a/74555697/53341

Comment: yes, `.apply()` is terribly slow, so that it would not be a significant improvement wrt a loop.