# Getting percent of totals in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe configured in the following way:

```
date_string | type | amount

 2015-01-01 |  a   | 500

 2015-01-01 |  b   | 300

 2015-01-01 |  c   | 200

 2015-01-02 |  a   | 400

 2015-01-02 |  b   | 600

 2015-01-02 |  c   | 100
```

I am looking to add a new column with the percent total broken down by date, and get something like this:

```
date_string | type | amount | percent

 2015-01-01 |  a   | 500    | 0.5

 2015-01-01 |  b   | 300    | 0.3

 2015-01-01 |  c   | 200    | 0.2

 2015-01-02 |  a   | 300    | 0.3

 2015-01-02 |  b   | 600    | 0.6

 2015-01-02 |  c   | 100    | 0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use groupby in pandas to calculate a perctentage/proportion total based on a criteria in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987829/how-to-use-groupby-in-pandas-to-calculate-a-perctentage-proportion-total-based-o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`, what is divided by original column by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df['percent'] = df['amount'].div(df.groupby('date_string')['amount'].transform('sum'))
print (df)
  date_string type  amount   percent
0  2015-01-01    a     500  0.500000
1  2015-01-01    b     300  0.300000
2  2015-01-01    c     200  0.200000
3  2015-01-02    a     400  0.363636
4  2015-01-02    b     600  0.545455
5  2015-01-02    c     100  0.090909
```

Comment: For other users.  `transform` is very efficient when using one of the available string options, `'sum'` in this case, as opposed to using a `lambda` within the `transform`.  So it is much better practice to do as @jezrael has done in dividing the current `'amount'` column by the results of the `transform('sum')`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it works! I will accept your answer as soon as I can (7 minutes)

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: His number make me think maybe df['percent'] = df.amount/1000 will work

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
import numpy as np
df.groupby(['amount', 'date_string']).sum().transform(lambda x: x/np.sum(x))
```