# pandas : most rapid way to convert values of big dataframe into percent (per row)

Tags: python, pandas

This question is not really the same as ["Getting percent of totals in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427481/getting-percent-of-totals-in-a-pandas-dataframe), even if it is not so far away.

Objective is, for a big dataframe filled by numerical values, to try to find the most rapid way to transform those values into percentage regarding each total rows. Here is an example:

```
# Dataframe filled with values :

    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   0   0   0
2   7   8   9

# to be transformed into percent per row:

    a       b       c
0   16.67   33.33   50.0
1   0.00    0.00    0.0
2   29.17   33.33   37.5
```

I've tried different ways to do that.

And the most rapid way I've found is the following (reproductive example):

```
# first import pandas and np
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# second, let's create the df
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
)
df
```

The above code, returns the df filled with values (note that one row is filled by zero values):

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   0   0   0
2   7   8   9
```

Then, let's declare a function which will do the job:

```
def transform_into_percent_vs_total_per_row(df):
    return (
        df
        # a total colum is created, sum per row
        .assign(total = lambda df: df.sum(axis=1))
        # each value is tranformed into percent versus total row
        .pipe(lambda x: x.div(x.total, axis=0)*100)
        # each percent is rounded 
        .round(2)
        # each nan percent coming from 0 value, is filled by a zero
        .fillna(0)
        # the total column is droped, because we do not need it
        .drop(columns=["total"])
    )

# previous function is piped to the df
df.pipe(transform_into_percent_vs_total_per_row)
```

The above code returns the df filled by percent per row as wished.

```
    a       b       c
0   16.67   33.33   50.0
1   0.00    0.00    0.0
2   29.17   33.33   37.5
```

This above code is rapid on a 12 millions rows x 200 columns dataframe, and more rapid than other code I've tried (like using `df.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x)*100, axis=1).round(2).fillna(0)` which is quiet long)

Do you have any other better idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100, fill_value=0).round(2)
```

Output:

```
       a      b     c
0  16.67  33.33  50.0
1   0.00   0.00   0.0
2  29.17  33.33  37.5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Numpy version for performance:

```
n = df.values
d = n.sum(1)[..., None]

np.divide(n*100, d, out=np.zeros_like(arr), where=d!=0).round(2)

array([[16.67, 33.33, 50.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [29.17, 33.33, 37.5 ]])
```

Performance:

```
# Pandas
%timeit df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100, fill_value=0).round(2)
1.1 ms ± 3.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Numpy
%timeit np.divide((n := df.values)*100, (d := n.sum(1)[..., None]), out=np.zeros_like(arr), where=d!=0).round(2)
21.3 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

Use vectorized operations with `div`, `sum` and `mul` on the right axis:

```
>>> df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).fillna(0)

           a          b     c
0  16.666667  33.333333  50.0
1   0.000000   0.000000   0.0
2  29.166667  33.333333  37.5
```