# Pandas: Get percent of numbe of elements which are not null after grouping by other column

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming that I have a dataframe with the following values:

```
    name     start    end     description
0    ag       20       30       None
1    bgb      21       111      'a'
2    cdd      31       101      None
3    bgb      17       19       None
4    ag       20       22       None
5    ag       1        65       'avc'
```

I want to groupby `name` and then get percent of number of `description` which is `not null` for every group `name`

For the example I show, I expect to see:

```
    name     percent 
0    ag       33.3      
1    bgb      50
2    cdd      0
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use groupby in pandas to calculate a percentage / proportion total based on a criteria in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987829/how-to-use-groupby-in-pandas-to-calculate-a-percentage-proportion-total-based)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate `mean` of boolean mask created by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html), then multiple by `100` and round if necessary:

```
df1 = (df['description'].notna()
                        .groupby(df['name'])
                        .mean()
                        .mul(100)
                        .round(2)
                        .reset_index(name='percent'))
print (df1)
  name  percent
0   ag    33.33
1  bgb    50.00
2  cdd     0.00
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = (df.assign(percent=df['description'].notna())
         .groupby('name')['percent']
         .mean()
         .mul(100)
         .round(2)
         .reset_index())
```

Comment: I am getting 100 percents for everything when running your code for the first example that you provided.

Comment: @DavidErickson - Because `None` are strings, use `df = df.replace({'description':{'None':None}})` before my solution

Comment: Got it, makes sense. That is good knowledge to have for future. I'm using pd.read_clipboard(), I'm assuming you are doing the same.

Comment: @DavidErickson - yes, pandas by default parse only NaNs, `None` are parsed by default like strings