# calculate percentage values depending on size group in dataframe - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
idx col1 col2 col3     
0   1.1    A  100    
1   1.1    A  100     
2   1.1    A  100  
3   2.6    B  100      
4   2.5    B  100        
5   3.4    B  100   
6   2.6    B  100
```

I want to update `col3` with percentage values depending on the group size of `col1`,`col2` (two columns ie., for each row having 1.1,A - col3 value should have `33.33`)

Desired output:

```
idx col1 col2 col3 
0 1.1 A 33.33
1 1.1 A 33.33 
2 1.1 A 33.33
3 2.6 B 50
4 2.5 B 100
5 3.4 B 100 
6 2.6 B 50
```

Comment: Can you add all desired output from input?

Comment: idx col1 col2 col3
0 1.1 A 33.33
1 1.1 A 33.33
2 1.1 A 33.33
3 2.6 B 50
4 2.5 B 100
5 3.4 B 100
6 2.6 B 50

Comment: It's a duplicate question. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby) is the answer to this question.

Comment: @AmitKulkarni I try modify duplicated answer for this question but no success. Can you add solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['col3'] = 100 / df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('size')
print df
     col1 col2        col3
idx                       
0     1.1    A   33.333333
1     1.1    A   33.333333
2     1.1    A   33.333333
3     2.6    B   50.000000
4     2.5    B  100.000000
5     3.4    B  100.000000
6     2.6    B   50.000000
```