# How to get percentage of counts of a column after groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, percentage

I'm trying to get the distribution of grades for each rank for names in a list of data.
However, I can't figure out how to get the proportion/percentage of each grade count over its rank group. Here's an example:

`df.head()`

```
name    rank    grade
Bob     1       A
Bob     1       A
Bob     1       B
Bob     1       C
Bob     2       B
Bob     3       C
Joe     1       C
Joe     2       B
Joe     2       B
Joe     3       A
Joe     3       B
Joe     3       B
```

I use `grade_count = df.groupby(['name', 'rank', 'grade']).['grade'].size())` to give me the count of each grade within its (name,rank) group:

```
name    rank    grade
Bob     1       A     2
                B     1
                C     1
        2       B     1
        3       C     1
Joe     1       C     1
        2       B     2
        3       A     1
                B     2
```

Now for each size calculated, I'd like to get its proportion to the (name,rank) group (i.e. what is the proportion of a grade within a rank, within a system) **This is the output I'd like**:

```
name    rank    grade
Bob     1       A     2    0.5   (Bob @ rank 1 had 4 grades, and 50% of them are A's)
                B     1    0.25
                C     1    0.25
        2       B     1    1
        3       C     1    1
Joe     1       C     1    1
        2       B     2    1
        3       A     1    0.33
                B     2    0.66
```

I've managed to get the totals of each rank group by using `rank_totals = grade_count.groupby(level[0,1]).sum()` which results in:

```
name    rank    
Bob     1       4
        2       1
        3       1
Joe     1       1
        2       2
        3       3
```

How can I divide the numbers from `grade_count` by their corresponding rank totals in `rank_totals`?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your data by name and rank levels, and use `transform` to get the total of your series and broadcast it to the entire Series. Use that series to divide the current one:

```
grade_count.groupby(level = [0,1]).transform(sum)
Out[19]: 
name  rank  grade
Bob   1     A        4
            B        4
            C        4
      2     B        1
      3     C        1
Joe   1     C        1
      2     B        2
      3     A        3
            B        3
dtype: int64

grade_count / grade_count.groupby(level = [0,1]).transform(sum)
Out[20]: 
name  rank  grade
Bob   1     A        0.500000
            B        0.250000
            C        0.250000
      2     B        1.000000
      3     C        1.000000
Joe   1     C        1.000000
      2     B        1.000000
      3     A        0.333333
            B        0.666667
```