# Pyspark: obtain percentage result after groupBy

Tags: python, sql, group-by, pyspark

For example, here is my test data

```
test = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 5, "2018-06-03", "Region A"),
    (1, 1, 2, "2018-06-04", "Region B"),
    (2, 2, 1, "2018-06-03", "Region B"),
    (3, 3, 1, "2018-06-01", "Region A"),
    (3, 1, 3, "2018-06-05", "Region A"),
])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "price", "transactiondate", "location")
test.show()
```

I can get summariztion data like this

```
test.groupBy("customerid", "location").agg(sum("price")).show()
```

[image]

but I also want the percentage data, something like this

```
+----------+--------+----------+ 
|customerid|location|sum(price)| percentage
+----------+--------+----------+ 
|         1|Region B|         2|    20%
|         1|Region A|         8|    80%
|         3|Region A|         1|    100%
|         2|Region B|         1|    100%
+----------+--------+----------+
```

I want to know

- How can I do it? maybe using a window function?
- Can I pivot table turn it into something like this? (with percentage and sum column)

[image]

---

I only find a pandas example at [How to get percentage of counts of a column after groupby in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40658129/how-to-get-percentage-of-counts-of-a-column-after-groupby-in-pandas)

UPDATE:

From the help of @Gordon Linoff, I can get the percentage by

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
test.groupBy("customerid", "location").agg(sum("price"))\
  .withColumn("percentage", col("sum(price)")/sum("sum(price)").over(Window.partitionBy(test['customerid']))).show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

In SQL, you can use window functions:

```
select customerid, location, sum(price),
       (sum(price) / sum(sum(price)) over (partition by customerid) as ratio
from t
group by customerid, location;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm able to get it work now. Great thanks to you. Addtionally, can I pivot the result? I've update my question

Comment: @cqcn1991 . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not by editing existing questions -- and even invalidating answers to them.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a clean code for your problem:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

(test.groupby("customerid", "location")
      .agg(F.sum("price").alias("t_price"))
      .withColumn("perc", F.col("t_price") / F.sum("t_price").over(Window.partitionBy("customerid")))
```