# Calculating percentage of filtered column attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to calculate the percentage of broken water points per community. So far, I am able to get the list of communities and the broken water points.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame((data))
gb = df.groupby(['water_point_condition'])
grouped = gb[["communities_villages", "water_point_condition"]].get_group("broken")
print(grouped)
```

The result is:

[image: results]

This fixed my problem and I was able to get percentage of broken water points per community:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
grouped = df.groupby(['water_point_condition'])
rank_by_percentage = 100 * df[df.water_point_condition == 'broken'].communities_villages.value_counts() / grouped["water_point_condition"].get_group("broken").count()
print(rank_by_percentage)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)  If that's not quite it, explore some of the comments and links there.  This is a common type of question here.

Comment: I was able to fix my error with the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by `ommunities_villages` and not `water_point_condition`

```
df.groupby('communities_villages')['water_point_condition'].apply(lambda x: (x == 'broken').mean())
```

Comment: Thank you @Ted Petrou. I was able to fix my error :)