# Add Groupby Percentage to Dataframe after Calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:
[image]

I need to calculate the percentage based on the `count` column which I already did following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby).

The result is this:

[image: Image2]

Now I need to add the results for the Groupby column back into the original DataFrame. I tried `grouped.reset_index()` and then adding it but I get an error `ValueError: cannot insert count, already exists` since the column used in the Group by is also used in the aggregation.

Can anyone help me to find a way to add the results back to the DataFrame?

Comment: You want the whole result to be added or only the count column?

Comment: Only the count column

Comment: Get into the habit of posting data and not images.  There are many reasons to hate images.  My reason is that I can't copy/paste it into my environment and produce more descriptive answers.

Comment: Will take it into account for future questions, thanks

Comment: Feel free to up vote the answer as well.  I'd appreciate it thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `transform` and that answer you linked could be better as well.

```
df.assign(
    NormalizedCount=df['count'] / df.groupby('suburb')['count'].transform('sum')
```