# Statistics for Grouped DataFrames with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame that can be grouped basically by two columns: `Level` and `Sub_level`.

The data looks like this:

```
    Level_1    Sub_level   Value

0    Group A   A1          100
1    Group A   A2          200
2    Group A   A1          150
3    Group B   B1          100
4    Group B   B2          200
5    Group A   A1          200
6    Group A   A1          300
7    Group A   A1          400
8    Group B   B2          450
...
```

I would like to get the frequency/count in each `Sub_level` compared to each comparable `Level_1`, i.e

```
Level_1   Sub_level   Pct_of_total

Group A   A1          5 / 6  (as there are 6 Group A instances in 'Level_1', and 5 A1:s in 'Sub_level')
          A2          1 / 6 
Group B   B1          1 / 3  (as there are 3 Group B instances in 'Level_1', and 1 B1:s in 'Sub_level')
          B2          2 / 3
```

Of course the fractions in the new column `Pct_of_total` should be expressed in
percentage.

Any clues?

Thanks,

/N

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for first `df` and then `groupby` by first level (`Level_1`) and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `sum`. Last divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Level_1','Sub_level'])['Value'].size()
print (df1)
Level_1  Sub_level
Group A  A1           5
         A2           1
Group B  B1           1
         B2           2
Name: Value, dtype: int64

df2 = df1.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
print (df2)
Level_1  Sub_level
Group A  A1           6
         A2           6
Group B  B1           3
         B2           3
Name: Value, dtype: int64

df3 = df1.div(df2).reset_index(name='Pct_of_total')
print (df3)
   Level_1 Sub_level  Pct_of_total
0  Group A        A1      0.833333
1  Group A        A2      0.166667
2  Group B        B1      0.333333
3  Group B        B2      0.666667
```