# Pandas: join on grouping keys after aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

## What I have

I have a pandas frame like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['31-05-2017', '31-05-2017', '31-05-2017', '31-05-2017', '01-06-2017', '01-06-2017'],
    'tag':     ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
    'metric1': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'metric2': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['31-05-2017', '31-05-2017', '01-06-2017'],
    'tag':     ['A', 'B', 'A'],
    'metric3': [25, 3, 7,]
})
```

## What I want

1) I want to sum `metric`and `metric_2` per each combination of `date` and `tag`

2) compute the percentage of entries being `1` in `metric_2`

3) merge grouped df1 with df2 so that I have `metric_3` for each `date`and `tag`

```
date       | tag | metric1_sum | metric2_sum | metric2_percentage| metric 3
-----------|-----|-------------|-------------|-------------------|---------
31-05-2017 | A   | 0           | 0           | 0                 | 25
31-05-2017 | B   | 1           | 2           | 0.667             | 3
01-06-2017 | A   | 1           | 0           | 0.5               | 7
```

## Attempts

### (1) group and sum works

```
>>> g = df1.groupby(['date', 'tag']).agg(sum)
>>> g
                metric1  metric2
date       tag                  
01-06-2017 A          2        1
31-05-2017 A          0        0
           B          1        2
```

### (2) calculating the percentage works but adding it as a column does not

I used the method [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23377232/1510622) to calculate the percentage.

```
>>> g2 = df1.groupby(['date', 'tag']).agg({'metric2': 'sum'})
>>> g2.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/float(x.sum()))
                metric2
date       tag         
01-06-2017 A        1.0
31-05-2017 A        0.0
           B        1.0
```

But, how can I now assign this grouped `metric2` to a column `metric2_percentage` in my groups `g` or my `df1`?

### (3) unsuccessful merge

Merging with the group apparently does not work:

```
>>> pd.merge(g, df2, how='left', on=['date', 'tag'])
KeyError: 'date'
```

How can I then reduce `df1` to one row per group so that I can merge it with `df2`?

Comment: Can you explain the problems between calculating the % and merging? Are these separate problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g` has `date, tag` as index, while `merge` is expecting columns, you'll need to reset_index on `g`:

```
pd.merge(g.reset_index(), df2, how='left', on=['date', 'tag'])
```

Or specify `left_index = True`:

```
pd.merge(g, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_on=['date', 'tag'])
```

Both give results as (with columns order slightly differ):

```
#         date  tag  metric1  metric2   metric3
#0  01-06-2017    A        2        1         7
#1  31-05-2017    A        0        0        25
#2  31-05-2017    B        1        2         3
```

---

Here is an alternative that does your job with one less join:

```
(df1.groupby(['date', 'tag']).apply(
        lambda g: pd.Series({'metric1_sum': g.metric1.sum(), 
                             'metric2_sum': g.metric2.sum(), 
                             'metric2_percentage': g.metric2.mean()})   
# assumed here you have only 1 and 0 in metric 2 column if not use your own lambda function
    ).reset_index().merge(df2, how='left', on=['date', 'tag']))

#         date  tag  metric1_sum    metric2_percentage  metric2_sum metric3
#0  01-06-2017    A          2.0              0.500000         1.0        7
#1  31-05-2017    A          0.0              0.000000         0.0       25
#2  31-05-2017    B          1.0              0.666667         2.0        3
```

Comment: Great, I was not aware that I can flatten the group with reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

Use `agg`.  `mean` of ones and zeros will be the same as percentage.

```
cols = ['date', 'tag']
d1 = df1.groupby(cols).agg(
    dict(metric1='sum', metric2=['sum', 'mean'])
)

d1.columns = d1.columns.map('_'.join)

d1.join(df2.set_index(cols))

         date tag  metric1_sum  metric2_sum  metric2_mean  metric3
0  01-06-2017   A            2            1      0.500000        7
1  31-05-2017   A            0            0      0.000000       25
2  31-05-2017   B            1            2      0.666667        3
```

---

Over-engineering for the sake of a one-liner

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df1.groupby(['date', 'tag']).agg(
    dict(metric1='sum', metric2=['sum', 'mean'])
).pipe(
    lambda d: pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict({'_'.join(k): v for k, v in d.iteritems()}))
).join(df2.set_index(['date', 'tag'])).reset_index()

         date tag  metric1_sum  metric2_sum  metric2_mean  metric3
0  01-06-2017   A            2            1      0.500000        7
1  31-05-2017   A            0            0      0.000000       25
2  31-05-2017   B            1            2      0.666667        3
```