# How to get percentages for each row and visualize categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I am doing exploratory data analysis on a Loan Prediction dataset (Pandas dataframe). This dataframe has two columns : Property_Area whose values are of three types - Rural, Urban, Semiurban. Another column is Loan_Status wise values are of two types - Y, N. I want to plot a graph like this: Along X-axis there should be Property_Area, and, for each type of 3 areas I want to show what % of loans accepted or rejected along the Y-axis. How to do that?

Here's an example of my data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Loan_Status':['N','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','Y','N','Y','N'], 
       'Property_Area': ['Rural', 'Urban','Urban','Urban','Urban','Urban',
       'Semiurban','Urban','Semiurban','Rural','Semiurban']})
```

I tried with this:

```
status = data['Loan_Status']
index = data['Property_Area']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Loan Status' : status}, index=index)
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)

data is the dataframe for the original dataset
```

Output:
[image]

**Edit:**
I was able to do what I wanted but, for that, I had to write a long code:

```
new_data = data[['Property_Area', 'Loan_Status']].copy()
count_rural_y = new_data[(new_data.Property_Area == 'Rural') & (data.Loan_Status == 'Y') ].count()
count_rural = new_data[(new_data.Property_Area == 'Rural')].count()
#print(count_rural[0])
#print(count_rural_y[0])
rural_y_percent = (count_rural_y[0]/count_rural[0])*100
#print(rural_y_percent)

#print("-"*50)

count_urban_y = new_data[(new_data.Property_Area == 'Urban') & (data.Loan_Status == 'Y') ].count()
count_urban = new_data[(new_data.Property_Area == 'Urban')].count()
#print(count_urban[0])
#print(count_urban_y[0])
urban_y_percent = (count_urban_y[0]/count_urban[0])*100
#print(urban_y_percent)

#print("-"*50)

count_semiurban_y = new_data[(new_data.Property_Area == 'Semiurban') & (data.Loan_Status == 'Y') ].count()
count_semiurban = new_data[(new_data.Property_Area == 'Semiurban')].count()
#print(count_semiurban[0])
#print(count_semiurban_y[0])
semiurban_y_percent = (count_semiurban_y[0]/count_semiurban[0])*100
#print(semiurban_y_percent)

#print("-"*50)

objects = ('Rural', 'Urban', 'Semiurban')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [rural_y_percent,urban_y_percent,semiurban_y_percent]
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Loan Approval Percentage')
plt.title('Area Wise Loan Approval Percentage')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Could you please suggest me a simpler way to do this, if possible?

Comment: When you say "it didn't work" what do you mean? Error? Didn't look like what you wanted? Please give us a little more to go on. Could you provide some sample or dummy data and a picture of what you've plotted so far?

Comment: Edited. Please see.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data. The given information is not sufficient enough to reproduce the issue as also pointed out by @G.Anderson too.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample data. I would start by bringing in the data as multiple columns, then doing a `groupby('Property_Area').count()' to get your actual value counts, then try plotting that

Comment: Regarding your edits, I'm glad you were able to solve it. This answer, [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby), gives a quick overview of creating an aggregation column based on percent of total. That might give you simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

### Pandas `Crosstabs` with `normalize` will make this simple

An easy way to take 2+ columns and get percentages for *each row* in a pandas dataframe is to use the `pandas` `crosstab` function with `normalize = 'index'`

---

**Here is how the crosstab function would look for it:**

```
# Crosstab with "normalize = 'index'". 
df_percent = pd.crosstab(data.Property_Area,data.Loan_Status,
                         normalize = 'index').rename_axis(None)

# Multiply all percentages by 100 for graphing. 
df_percent *= 100
```

*This would output `df_percent` that would look like this:*

```
Loan_Status          N          Y
Rural        50.000000  50.000000
Semiurban    66.666667  33.333333
Urban        16.666667  83.333333
```

**You can then plot this into your barchart very easily:**

```
# Plot only approvals as bar graph. 
plt.bar(df_percent.index, df_percent.Y, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.ylabel('Loan Approval Percentage')
plt.title('Area Wise Loan Approval Percentage')

plt.show()
```

*And get the resulting chart:*

[image: Matplotlib bar plot from pandas crosstab]

**[Here you can see the code working in google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VtMSdMy396U6BGVdz2qRsgRveYW9uTHi)**

---

***Here is the example dataframe I generated for this answer:***

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Loan_Status':['N','Y','Y','Y','Y','N','N','Y','N','Y','Y'
   ], 'Property_Area': ['Rural', 'Urban','Urban','Urban','Urban','Urban',
   'Semiurban','Urban','Semiurban','Rural','Semiurban']})
```

Creates this example dataframe:

```
   Loan_Status Property_Area
0            N         Rural
1            Y         Urban
2            Y         Urban
3            Y         Urban
4            Y         Urban
5            N         Urban
6            N     Semiurban
7            Y         Urban
8            N     Semiurban
9            Y         Rural
10           Y     Semiurban
```