# Grouping multiple columns and return percentage for each column passed

Tags: python, pandas

I've made a kmeans cluster with n_cluster = 5, so I want to groupby cluster and return for each column the percentage respect to the other cluster.

This is how my original df looks:

```
    Cluster  poor  vul_car  plb
0   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
1   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
2   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
3   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
4   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
5   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
6   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
7   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
8   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
9   0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
10  0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
11  0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
12  0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
13  0   0.572721    0.271329    0.618297
```

```
df_cl.groupby('Cluster')['poor','vul_car','plb'].apply(lambda g: g / g.sum())
```

but when I run the code above, it return  a small df with 8 rows when it should return only five (one for each cluster)

This is the output i got:

```
    poor          vul_car   plb
0   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
1   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
2   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
3   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
4   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
5   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
6   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
7   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
8   0.000009    0.000013    0.000010
```

UPDATE

Adding the df grouoby by sum()

```
          poor          vul_car     plb
Cluster             
0   60301.445261    21240.180253    63394.338941
1   3393.607959     3667.498423     4294.861767
2   3957.179616     3924.170072     4917.699755
3   2103.213416     1941.625432     2597.529967
4   10184.192563    6303.950323     11575.100528
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? The output and the input data you are using before the function?

Comment: Hi, it's much easier to help you if you provide a [mcve]

Comment: What's the index of said rows? From your code, there should be 8 unique values in your `Cluster` column

Comment: could you provide a sample of your df?  :)

Comment: What happens if you add `axis=1` to your apply?

Comment: thank you for the update. The data is still not enough to test your code but try with aggregating it first with `groupby('Cluster')['poor','vul_car','plb'].sum()` and please share the results

Comment: @Yuca done it! you can see now the output for sum() groupby

Comment: ok, then it looks like a transform would fit better what you need. Sadly I'm a little to rusty with my pandas manipulation but give it 30 minutes and one of the mvps should give you a beautiful answer. In the meantime, you should check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby

Comment: All three columns would be the same in your expected output? You're trying to get which percentage of your rows is each Cluster? Could you providen an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = df_cl.groupBy('Cluster').count().select(avg("poor"))
d2 = df_cl.groupBy('Cluster').count().select(avg("vul_car"))
d3 = df_cl.groupBy('Cluster').count().select(avg("plb"))

new_df = pd.concat([d1, d2, d3], axis=1)

print(new_df)
```