# pandas groupby and transform only one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to groupby and transform only one of the grouped columns.

Suppose I have dataframe like this:

```
dataf = pd.DataFrame({'question': ['q1', 'q1', 'q1', 'q2', 'q2', 'q2', 'q3', 'q3', 'q3']*10, 'value': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]*10})
datafG = dataf.groupby(['question', 'value']).agg({'value': 'count'})
datafG['sum_n'] = datafG.groupby(['question']).transform('sum')
```

And then I want to groupby and get proportions of the count column `datafG / datafG.groupby(level=[0]).transform('sum')` this will however transform both, I am looking for a way to keep my `sum_n`column as it is.

This gives me a df looking like this:

```
                    value   sum_n
question    value   
q1          1       0.33    0.33
q1          2       0.33    0.33
q1          3       0.33    0.33
q2          1       0.33    0.33
q2          2       0.33    0.33
q2          3       0.33    0.33
q3          1       0.33    0.33
q3          2       0.33    0.33
q3          3       0.33    0.33
```

While I want:

```
                    value   sum_n
question    value   
q1          1       0.33    30
q1          2       0.33    30
q1          3       0.33    30
q2          1       0.33    30
q2          2       0.33    30
q2          3       0.33    30
q3          1       0.33    30
q3          2       0.33    30
q3          3       0.33    30
```

Comment: add a dataframe showing your expected output.

Comment: ```dataf.groupby(...)[column_u_want_to_agg].count()``` ?

Comment: The outcome you are getting now and the outcome you want to get would be helpful!

Comment: But it sounds like this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby

Comment: looks like you need `datafG['sum_n'] = datafG.groupby(level=0)['value'].transform('sum')` ?

Comment: I have updated with expected output