# Python percentage of 2 columns in new column based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have asked earlier this question and got some feedback however I am still stuck in some mystery where I am not able to calculate the percentage of 2 columns based on conditions. 2 columns are ‘tested population’ and ‘total population’ based on grouping ‘Year’ & ‘Gender’ and show it in new column as ‘percentage’…

```
 Year   Race    Gender  Tested population   Total population
2017    Asian     Male      345              567
2017    Hispanic  Female    666              67899
2018    Native    Male      333              35543
2018    Asian     Female    665              78955
2019    Hispanic  Female    4444             44356
2020    Native  Male        3642             6799
2017    Asian   Male        5467             7998
2018    Asian   Female      5467             7998
2019    Hispanic    Male    456              4567
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyXCX.png)
    code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(alldata, columns=['Year', 'Gender', 'Tested population', 'Total population'])


df2 = df.groupby(['Year', 'Gender']).agg({'Tested population': 'sum'})
pop_pcts = df2.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x:
                                                 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
print(pop_pcts)
```

Output:

```
    Tested population
Year Gender                   
2017 Female          10.280951
     Male            89.719049
2018 Female          94.849188
     Male             5.150812
2019 Female          90.693878
     Male             9.306122
2020 Male           100.000000
```

Whereas i want data as in this format to show along with other columns as a new column 'Percentage' .

```
Year    Race    Gender  Tested population   Total population    Percentage
2017    Asian   Male             345                  567       60.8466
2017    Hispanic    Female       666                  67899     0.98087
2018    Native  Male             333                  35543     0.93689
2018    Asian   Female           665                  78955     0.84225
2019    Hispanic    Female       4444                 44356    10.0189
2020    Native  Male             3642                 6799     53.5667
2019    Hispanic    Male         456                  4567     9.98467
```

I have gone through [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)
and not able to fix my issues, can someone help on this

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Percentage'] = df['Tested population']/df['Total Population']
```

I believe you just need to add a column.

Comment: the final what i want is to calculate the percentage of 2 columns based on conditions. 2 columns are ‘tested population’ and ‘total population’ based on grouping ‘Year’ & ‘Gender’ and show it in new column as ‘percentage’