# Dividing Two Dataframe Columns after Groupby to order time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm working with 20 years of data. The important columns right now are YEAR, MONTH, NUM1, and NUM2. How can I get the monthly percent of NUM1/NUM2?

```
YEAR | MONTH | NUM1 | NUM2 |
------------------------------
2000 |  6    |  60  | 100  |
2000 |  6    |  55  | 100  |
2000 |  2    | 80    | 160 |

to

YEAR | MONTH | NUM1 | NUM2 |  PCT  |
-------------------------------------
2000 |  2    | 80    | 160 |  50   |
2000 |  6    |  60  | 100  |  57.5 |
2000 |  6    |  55  | 100  |  57.5 |
```

What I want to do is

```
df2 = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'MONTH'], as_index=False)
df2['PCT'] = df2['NUM1']/df2['NUM2']
```

However, I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DataFrameGroupBy' and 'DataFrameGroupBy'`

When I run `type(df2)` it returns `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy`. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? It should be pretty simple to order data in chronological order and then divide to columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `transform`

```
g = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'MONTH'])
df['PCT']=g.NUM1.transform('sum')/g.NUM2.transform('sum')*100
df
   YEAR  MONTH  NUM1  NUM2   PCT
0  2000      6    60   100  57.5
1  2000      6    55   100  57.5
2  2000      2    80   160  50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': [2000, 2001, 2000, 2000],
                   'MONTH': [2, 4, 6, 2],
                   'sales': [2000, 2001, 2000, 2003],
                   'price': [2020, 2200, 20020, 20023]})

#df.head()

#data.groupby('month', as_index=False).agg({"duration": "sum"})

state_office = df.groupby(['YEAR', 'MONTH']).agg({'sales':"sum","price":"sum"})

state_office['PCT'] = (state_office['sales']/state_office['price']).mul(100)
state_office.head()
```

You didnt define the operation to performed on the column
Hope this answers your queries.

Related links - [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)