# How to use pandas groupby to calculate percentage of total in each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains 4 columns: id, color, flag_1 and flag_2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(0,5),
                   'color': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'],
                   'flag_1':[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  'flag_2':[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]})
```

Different from this question: [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby), i want to group by the column color and get the percentage of total of **both**, flag_1 and flag_2.

The result should look like this data frame:

```
color    flag_1  flag_2
red       0.5     1
blue       0     0.67
```

I can't seem to figure out how to adapt the code from the cited question that aggregates just one column, to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `crosstab`:

```
m = df.drop("id", axis=1).melt("color")
pd.crosstab(m.color, m.variable, m.value, aggfunc="mean").rename_axis(None)


variable    flag_1  flag_2
blue         0.0    0.666667
red          0.5    1.000000
```

Sticking to groupby :

```
df.groupby("color", sort=False).agg(flag1=("flag_1", "mean"), flag2=("flag_2", "mean"))


       flag1    flag2
color       
red     0.5     1.000000
blue    0.0     0.666667
```