# How to work out percentage of total with groupby for specific columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Name','Status','Profit','Promotion','Product','Visits']) 
df['Name'] = ['Andy','Andy','Brad','Brad','Cynthia','Cynthia']
df['Status'] =['Old','New','Old','New','Old','New'] 
df['Profit'] = [140,60,110,90,20,100]
df['Promotion'] = [25,30,40,10,22,36]
df['Product'] = [8,6,18,10,7,12]
df['Visits'] = [11,4,7,3,12,5]
df['Month'] = 'Jan'
```

I would like to work out the percentage of total for the columns 'Profit','Promotion' and 'Product' by 'Name' in order to achieve the following dataframe:

```
df['Profit'] = [70,30,55,45,17,83]
df['Promotion'] = [45,55,80,20,38,62]
df['Product'] = [57,43,64,36,37,63]
df
```

I have attempted to group by 'Name','Status' and 'Month' and tried doing something similar to the solution provided here [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby) but can't seem to get my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for sum per `Name`s with divide original columns, multiple by 100 and last `round`:

```
cols = ['Profit','Promotion','Product']

print (df.groupby('Name')[cols].transform('sum'))
   Profit  Promotion  Product
0     200         55       14
1     200         55       14
2     200         50       28
3     200         50       28
4     120         58       19
5     120         58       19

df[cols] = df[cols].div(df.groupby('Name')[cols].transform('sum')).mul(100).round()
print (df)
      Name Status  Profit  Promotion  Product  Visits Month
0     Andy    Old    70.0       45.0     57.0      11   Jan
1     Andy    New    30.0       55.0     43.0       4   Jan
2     Brad    Old    55.0       80.0     64.0       7   Jan
3     Brad    New    45.0       20.0     36.0       3   Jan
4  Cynthia    Old    17.0       38.0     37.0      12   Jan
5  Cynthia    New    83.0       62.0     63.0       5   Jan
```