# Calculate percentage of grouped values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like"

[image]

I calculated the number of Win, Lost and Draw for each year, and now it looks like:

[image]

My goal is to calculate the percentage of each score group by year. To become like:
[image]

But I stuck here.
I looked in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby/46105516#46105516) but was not able to apply it on my df.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is quite a simple method I wrote for this task:

Just do as follows:

1. create a dataframe of the total score within each year:

- `total_score = df.groupby('year')['score'].sum().reset_index(name = 'total_score_each_year')`

2. merge the original and the new dataframe into a single dataframe:

- `df = df.merge(total_score, on = 'year')`

3. calculate the percents:

- `df['percentages'] = 100 * (df['score'] / df['total_score_each_year'])`

That's it, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using : `df.iat[row, column]`

it would look something like this:

```py
percentages = []
for i in range(len(df) // 3):
  draws = df.iat[i, 2]
  losses = df.iat[i + 1, 2]
  wins = df.iat[i + 2, 2]
  nbr_of_games = draws + losses + wins
  percentages.append[draws * 100/nbr_of_games] #Calculate percentage of draws
  percentages.append[losses * 100/nbr_of_games] #Calculate percentage of losses
  percentages.append[wins * 100/nbr_of_games] #Calculate percentage of wins

df["percentage"] = percentages
```

This may not be the fastest way to do it but i hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @panter answer, but in only one line and without creating any additional DataFrame:

```py
df['percentage'] = df.merge(df.groupby('year').score.sum(), on='year', how='left').apply(
    lambda x: x.score_x * 100 / x.score_y,  axis=1
)
```

In detail:

1. `df.groupby('year').score.sum()` creates a DataFrame with the sum of the `score` per year.
2. `df.merge` creates a Dataframe equal to the original `df`, but with the column `score` renamed to `score_x` and an additional column `score_y`, that represents the sum of all the scores for the year of each row; the `how='left'` keeps only row in the left DataFrame, i.e., `df`.
3. `.apply` computes for each the correspondent percentage, using `score_x` and `score_y` (mind the `axis=1` option, to apply the lambda row by row).

Comment: nice one-liner :)