# Python pandas calculate share of after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation, percentage

I want to group below type of dataset by postalcodes and calculate the share of completed orders each shipping method has per postalcode.
I've implemented a csv-file and tried the code below but i realized I need MultiIndex for that - and since I have a loot of different postalcodes I'm not sure how to go with it.

| postalcode | shipping_method | completed_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | post1 | 1 |
| 12345 | post2 | 3 |
| 12345 | post3 | 2 |
| 11123 | post1 | 1 |
| 11123 | post2 | 2 |

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

shipping_data = pd.read_csv("shipping_per_postalcode.csv")

shareof = lambda x: x/x.sum()
result = shipping_data['amount_users_completed'].groupby(level=['postalcode', 'shipping_option']).transform(sumto)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need additional groupby to get the percentage contribution

```
df_agg=df_1.groupby(['postalcode', 'shipping_method'])['completed_orders'].sum()

df_agg.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100*x/float(x.sum()))
```

[image]

Source: [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)

Comment: Wow, I really complicated it for myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome @SevgiCamuz ! Please upvote the answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Def! :) Do you know why the column name for share of completed orders disapears?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
result = df['completed_orders'] / df.groupby(['postalcode'])['completed_orders'].transform(sum)

# Out[43]:
# 0    0.166667
# 1    0.500000
# 2    0.333333
# 3    0.333333
# 4    0.666667
# Name: completed_orders, dtype: float64
```