# pandas-calculate percentage in specfic group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My input dataframe: **df1**

```
line_item_product_code  cost Account     
AWSCloudTrail            10  AU-MGT   
AWSGlue                  12  AU-MGT  
AWSQueueService          15  AU-MGT   
AWSSecretsManager        20  AU-PRD  
AmazonDynamoDB           30  AU-PRD
```

I want to calculate the percentage based on specific account

Output dataframe:

```
line_item_product_code  cost Account     percentage
AWSCloudTrail            10  AU-MGT      27.02 
AWSGlue                  12  AU-MGT      32.43
AWSQueueService          15  AU-MGT      40.54
AWSSecretsManager        20  AU-PRD      40
AmazonDynamoDB           30  AU-PRD      60
```

How can I achieve this in pandas?
Example Calculation for AU-MGT and AWSCloudTrail:

```
percentage = 10*100/(10+12+15)
```

Comment: How did you get the percentage values @PPARI1

Comment: @Vishnudev added an sample calculation in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple [`groupby` + `transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) should do the trick:

```
>>> df['percentage'] = df['cost'] / df.groupby('Account')['cost'].transform('sum') * 100
>>> df
  line_item_product_code  cost Account  percentage
0          AWSCloudTrail    10  AU-MGT   27.027027
1                AWSGlue    12  AU-MGT   32.432432
2        AWSQueueService    15  AU-MGT   40.540541
3      AWSSecretsManager    20  AU-PRD   40.000000
4         AmazonDynamoDB    30  AU-PRD   60.000000
```

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby) addresses the efficiency of different methods to calculate percentages per group.