# How to count percentage of certain values in column in group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id       is_good
a1        1
a1        1
a1        0
bb        1
bb        0
bb        0
bb        0
```

I want to count percentage of 0 and 1 for each id. So desired result is:

```
id       is_good_perc
a1        0.67
bb        0.25
```

How to do that? What should I do after `groupby("id")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas percentage of total with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby)

Comment: ``df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['is_good'].mean()``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General case:

```py
df.groupby("id").is_good.value_counts(normalize=True)

# id  is_good
# a1  1          0.666667
#     0          0.333333
# bb  0          0.750000
#     1          0.250000
# Name: is_good, dtype: float64
```

In your case, because you have binary variables, I'd take advantage of what @sushanth put in the comments and use `df.groupby('id')['is_good'].mean()`.