# Python pandas to calculate percentage of groupby sums?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to calculate the relative percentages of a sum of a particular column of a dataframe after I have grouped by a different column. The format of the data frame would be for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3', 'Company1', 'Company3'],
                   'STC Watts': [10.10, 9.6, 13.3, 5.6, 10.12],
                   ...other columns
                     )
```

At this point I need to group by the "Company" columns and get the total sum of "STC Watts" column for each company, but I would also like to have a relative percentage of that company "STC Watts" sum out of the total for the entire dataset. I tried using a couple solutions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23377108/pandas-percentage-of-total-with-groupby) but could not get any of them to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post-process the [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) adding a new column with the division by the total (optional multiplied by 100 for percent, and eventually rounded):

```
out = (
 df.groupby('Company', as_index=False)['STC Watts'].sum()
   .assign(percent=lambda d: d['STC Watts'].div(d['STC Watts'].sum())
                                           .mul(100).round(2)
           )
)
```

Output:

```
    Company  STC Watts  percent
0  Company1      15.70    32.22
1  Company2       9.60    19.70
2  Company3      23.42    48.07
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3', 'Company1', 'Company3'],
                   'STC Watts': [10.10, 9.6, 13.3, 5.6, 10.12]})
new_df = df.groupby('Company').sum()
new_df['percent'] = ((new_df['STC Watts'] / new_df['STC Watts'].sum()) * 100).round(2)
new_df
```

The output would be:

```
          STC Watts  percent
Company                     
Company1      15.70    32.22
Company2       9.60    19.70
Company3      23.42    48.07
```